# USB data transfer rates lower than expected

Tags: usb, performance, usb-drive

USB "data transfer rate" on Ubuntu 11.04 is 13MB/sec. This should be about 5x that for USB 2.0.

Anyone have a clue why I am getting USB 1.0 speed out of a modern mainboard with zero USB 1.0 ports and only USB 2.0?

Comment: well, which mainboard it is ? and what usb drive ? do you mean bits or bytes when you type MB ( people sometimes types it wrong ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the data transfer rate so slow on my external USB 2.0 drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41287/why-is-the-data-transfer-rate-so-slow-on-my-external-usb-2-0-drive)

Comment: USB 1.0 is not that fast. 13 MB/s = 13 × 8 = 104 Mb/s. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.0) says it's limited to 12 Mb/s which is 1.5 MB/s.

Comment: What usb drive are you using to connect to the usb 2.0 port? if your drive is slow or damaged that could reflect on the speed it copies data!

Comment: Do you have another computer on which you can check the drive? Or do you have another drive to test on the computer?

Answer (score 3):

Do not rely on the "theorical speeds". They will never be accomplished by somebody unless they are in the perfect conditions. The perfect conditions include:

- Correct altitude (How high or low you are influences)
- Position (If you are in a city next to a power generator is not the same as in a farm)
- Correct motherboard... scratch that... PERFECT motherboard to usb configuration (including the minerals used to create the part of the motherboard to connect to the usb and give those speeds)
- And last... you have to be in the moon for it to work perfect ;)

What am saying here is that none of the said speeds have been accomplished. None. they have only be accomplished on the labs where they made it under very strict conditions. This is why I get a little angry when they say for example:

USB 1.0 Full - 1.5MB/Sec <-- Not true. I always get between 100KB to 350KB. You might get a little more but not 1.5MB FTW!!

USB 2.0 - 60MB/Sec <--- Really? Ya Really? If you have a good motherboard and when I say good motherboard I mean one that has proven at least for a year to give good results and not some cheap one, then you might get to 40MB/Sec. I can give an example of the following which applies to many other motherboards. I have an Intel DP35DP. The front usb panel says that it supports 2.0 but somehow they do not run as fast as the back usb connections. This is true for most motherboards. In this example you can see that you have both USB supporting 2.0 but not both have the same speed because it depends on 2 things: You motherboard connection to that specific usb connector and your usb pen drive. I have 2 USB 2.0 pen drive. Both are 32GB but see here. One is Kingston Data Traveler and the other one is Sandisk. I for one are one of those that when somebody says Crucial, Kingston or Corsair and know they are good. when I tested both, in all tests Sandisk had 2x to 3x times faster speed than Kingston.

This made me know that, even on the same motherboard, different pen drives can have different speeds. And this changes on other motherboards. So there is no "only speed" for a pen drive when testing it out on several mother boards. I have to say that the max speed Sandisk gave me was 32MB/Sec to 38MB/Sec while the max Kingston gave me was 11MB/Sec to 13MB/Sec.

Now lets go to the motherboard configuration before going to the OS. My motherboard and many, MANY others have an option in the BIOS (When you cold boot the PC press like crazy F2, DEL, F10 or ESC) until you enter: THE BIOS!

In the BIOS look for an option that says High Speed or Full Speed. I find it dumb that one says HIGH and the other FULL because is misleading but whatever. Select High Speed to get the 480Mb speed (Or 60MB/Sec). Full speed is just about 12Mb (Or about 1.5MB/Sec). But remember even if you save it to High Speed you will not get some crazy 60MB/Sec on your pen drive, not even external usb hard drive.

Now after doing the BIOS part enter Ubuntu and do some tests and run some commands like 'sudo lsusb -v' to get some info on the USB ports. also you can try 'lshw' for more info on the motherboard.

Before I end this I wish this helps in understanding the problem that hunts us all about USB 2.0 and the "speed" it should have. This should solve the doubts we all have with USB ports, where to look for the problem and some knowledge about how the USB makers "make up" some weird speeds in TheoryLand but do not apply on RealWorldLand. Good luck.